# What if just want to make some text BOLD in question? which is posted by other user

Tags: support, questions

I just tried to make some text **BOLD** in question which is posted by someone else. But it says me : **Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?**

Some time it happens that all description of question is proper , just need to highlight some text then how can we do that? does that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edits must be at least 6 characters;

That simply is there to prevent excessive editing sprees. Keep in mind that after the 10th edit of a question (by all users who edited a question), the question automatically turns into a community wiki. And when that happens, you loose all reputation points (and possible privileges that go along with it) from that question.

> [...] is there something else to improve in this post?

There *always* is something that you can add to a question :)

Link to sources or reference material for example. Or explain what an API function *really* does. Just adding markup doesn't really add *value*. It's easier to read, but it doesn't necessarily help understanding what you tried to explain.

Last note: In case you were [talking about this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/175385/385) (I know you didn't, but it jumped at me), then please: Take a look at the WYSIWG editor buttons. There's a button for `code` formatting. Do *not* format code as *bold*, but format it as it is: Code.

There're also buttons for lists, etc. On the **upper right** side of the editor window, you will find a small yellow `(?)` question mark in a circle. It points [to the editing help](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page. Please take a look at this page.

Hope that helped :)

Comment: Thanks for answer , I am talking about this : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175379/get-categories-returns-uncategorized-solved                              Here that user has put note with question that SOLVED, I tried to make that BOLD but not able to do that. So can you please tell me how can I do that text BOLD?

Comment: @HelpingHands Got you. Please do not encourage users to just update their question with _SOLVED_. As you can read in the [help], there's more to it: Questions need answers - or close votes ("too localized" for example). Else we will stay on an even bigger pile of unanswered questions. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I have not encouraged them. When I noticed that user has updated it as SOLVED so I thought let me make that text BOLD so other user do not waste their time to solve that.

Comment: @HelpingHands That was a nice move. But the StackExchange network has you covered and helps you making that even faster: Flag it as "too localized" and move over to the next question. Kool that you are so motivated, your name fits you quite well :)

Comment: Yeah , thanks..:)